# Find what other projects use this project as a maven dependency?

Tags: java, maven, artifactory

We use Artifactory to store our maven generated java artifacts. We have many interrelated projects that depend on each other. Is it possible with maven or with Artifactory to look pick a single artifact and look for all projects that have that as a dependency?

In the example below, I want to find what projects use artifact1 v1.0.0. I would like to be able to use maven/Artifactory to find the fact that artifact2 depends on this version of the dependency, but not find artifact3/4 which don't. Ideally it would also be nice to find artifact2 if I was just looking for uses of artifact1 regardless of version.

```
    <project>
        <groupId>mygroup</groupId>
        <artifactId>artifact1</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </project>


    <project>
        <groupId>mygroup</groupId>
        <artifactId>artifact2</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>

        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>mygroup</groupId>
                <artifactId>artifact1</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </project>

    <project>
        <groupId>mygroup</groupId>
        <artifactId>artifact3</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>

        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>mygroup</groupId>
                <artifactId>artifact1</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.0</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </project>

    <project>
        <groupId>mygroup</groupId>
        <artifactId>artifact4</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>

        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>mygroup</groupId>
                <artifactId>otherartifact</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </project>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is pretty much one of the main reasons why you would use Artifactory in the first place.
Artifactory provides a very extensive search capability in the form of its [AQL](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+Query+Language), which does exactly what you're asking for.

As an example for your case running something like:

```
builds.find(
        {"module.dependency.item.name":{"$match":"*artifact1*"}}
    ).include("module.artifact.name")
```

will return all builds that had `Artifact1` as a dependency (you can also add an `"$and"` clause to limit this to a specific version of `Arifact1`), the include at the end will return all artifacts that were part of the module that had `Artifact1` as a dependency (so that's where you will see `Artifact2` in your case)

Here is an example output I got when running this query on a simple maven build called `multi-module-build` that had several modules where one of them (`multi3`) had a dependency called `multi1`:

```
"results" : [ {
    "build.created" : "2016-03-10T09:08:51.283+02:00",
    "build.created_by" : "admin",
    "build.name" : "multi-module-build",
    "build.number" : "10",
    "build.url" : "http://localhost:9090/jenkins/job/multi-shmulti/10/",
    "modules" : [ {
    "artifacts" : [ {
            "artifact.name" : "multi3-3.6-SNAPSHOT.war"
        }, {
            "artifact.name" : "multi3-3.6-SNAPSHOT.pom"
        } ]
    } ]
 } ]
```

Comment: Thanks for that. It's close, but not quite what I'm looking for. One problem I have is that I think the builds.find AQL is only in relatively recent version of Artifactory (I'm slightly behind). Doesn't this also rely on me having build integration to tell artifactory about builds? Shouldn't I just be able to do this off the artifacts and poms themselves, not just the builds they were built from?

Comment: builds in AQL are supported since 4.2.  In any case Artifactory relies on metadata that your build publishes (i.e. using CI plugins), how would you expect to achieve stuff like this without any data on your artifacts...?

Comment: I would have thought in theory all you need is the pom. The pom tells me what depends on what, not the build that created the jar.

Comment: Basically that's a correct assumption, but the way Artifactory handles this is with build information.
Might make for an interesting feature request though...  https://www.jfrog.com/jira

Comment: Fair enough, thanks for your help :) I'll accept this answer, but I'd love one that didn't involve builds.

Comment: @Kieran By looking at this old comment http://forums.jfrog.org/Viewing-depending-artifacts-tp4945156p5726670.html I believe that publishing CI builds to Artifactoy is the only reliable way to do this.