# Eclipse - How to see which projects have a maven dependency on a selected project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

Is there an easy way within Eclipse to see which other projects in my Eclipse workspace that have a maven dependency on a selected project?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find what other projects use this project as a maven dependency?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35888073/find-what-other-projects-use-this-project-as-a-maven-dependency)

Comment: Ah that's not quite what I was looking for but actually still very helpful, I was wondering if there was a way to do this except specifically only with the projects in your eclipse workspace and not through some repository manager